# How do I create an ajax link?

Tags: ajax, 8, navigation

I want to create an ajax linking a view (front page, for example).
I create an ajax edit link to edit content directely in the node. I success to add a link but when i click to it, a popin was opened(to edit content). 
I know how to make it in Drupal 7, but I don't find the solution for Drupal 8.

This is the code I am using.

```
    $build['ajax_edit_link'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'links',
    '#weight' => -2,
    '#links' => array(
      'ajax_edit_link' => array(
        'title' => t('Edit'),
        'url' => $entity->urlInfo('edit-form'),
        'attributes' => array(
          'class' => array('use-ajax'),
          'data-dialog-type' => 'dialog',
          'data-dialog-options' => Json::encode(array(
            'width' => 1200,
            'height' => 500,
          ))
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Here is all captures of the result of this edit ajax link in Drupal 8 (popin).

[image: Node in the front page -Capture 1 - Drupal 8]

[image]

And here are the capture I want to make in Drupal 8 (Capture in Drupal 7 site).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I haven't done this yet but see how Block Layout page is doing it.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is missing one part that I can see, the `#attached` key:

```
  $build['ajax_edit_link'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'links',
    '#weight' => -2,
    '#links' => array(
      'ajax_edit_link' => array(
        'title' => t('Edit'),
        'url' => $entity->urlInfo('edit-form'),
        'attributes' => array(
          'class' => array('use-ajax'),
          'data-dialog-type' => 'dialog'
          'data-dialog-options' => Json::encode(array(
            'width' => 1200,
            'height' => 500,
          ))
        ),
      ),
    ),
    '#attached' => array('library' => array('core/drupal.ajax')),
  );
```